# asp.net or windows service that listen to if you get a Email

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, email, service

I am trying to make a program that will listen to if I recieve a E-mail I got a smtp server and so on.
I want to make a database object with Title and text from the Mail and I might want to evolve it into also saving the attacted file to the database so I can use it it my asp.net program.

I think I need a windows Service that will be listening to the email if it gets a email it will add it to datbase and wait again but I am not sure how to do that. if its possible to program that into my asp.net project then it would be a good thing also

Here is a small design on how I was thinking about it

[image: The Image of how I was seeing the process to be done]

if you know anything about it feel free to come up with any kind of solutions for me.

Comment: Personally I like the solution you propose which uses a windows service for checking (and storing) incoming mails. It should be a small application and you could even use the same domain objects for mails, attachments etc in the asp.net project you (I assume) you will use to view the database content with.

Comment: yup I use the asp.net to read data from asp.net. Its a helpdesk system I am making and I want people to be able to host a helpdesk by sending in a E-mail so basicly my asp.net read in the database were all my tickets and so on are and then I want the windows service to make a new ticket when recieving a E-mail and so far I seen it should be a windows service yes. but now its time to figure out how to make such a simple code xD hehe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I figured out a good solution for this problem friends :)

What I did was I downloaded the [EAGetMail](http://www.emailarchitect.net/eagetmail/) and implamentet it. it basicly works for you in a time interval it will check your mail and make a txt file with all the mails so it wont read it again. it also got a aplication field so everytime it runs it will run the selected application.
So I made a console application that runs trough my folder where it will save all my email's as .eml file. It will check for a sub folder called read if its not there then create it and then check the root folder for .eml files read them and save information from it to the database and then move the file to read.
We did not want to use pop3 cuz we wanted the mails to stay intact så we dont lose any information. so we ran for the IMAP4.
and in the asp.net I just run a query that checks the database and use the files.

Answer (score 0):

Read incoming emails with POP3 or Exchange. I've made something similar before, which was a system where users could add links (a type of linking-scam actually) to different websites. So there was a bunch of people in Asia that had a full-time job searching for relevant sites and emailing a list of these URL's to a specific email-address. A service I had running would check the POP3 inbox every 5 minutes or so and then post these links to the website.

You should make an application that gets run at specific intervals rather than a service, which is much simpler. If you're using Azure as a host you can use the scheduled task service there to make a POST call to a page on your site so you don't have to run the code in a different eco-system. Well, I guess you can do that anyway with scheduled tasks in windows.

[Here's a POP3 client for .NET](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hpop/)

Comment: We are running Microsoft sql server

Answer (score 0):

You could make a C# service that checks the pop3 server in a configured interval, and store them in the DB. There's something like this here:
http://aspsnippets.com/Articles/Fetch-and-Read-emails-from-POP3-mail-server-using-C-and-VB.Net---Part-I.aspx
But as a regular application, you just have to make it to run as service (I think you have a project template for that in VS). You have some info here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a(v=vs.110).aspx